# How to set up parse-server for accessing legacy PFFiles

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Is the following set of keys sufficient for setting up Parse-Server on AWS, such that it can see and access the PFFiles that are still managed by Parse.

```
    PARSE_MOUNT: "/parse"
    APP_ID: "ReplaceWithAppID"
    MASTER_KEY: "ReplaceWithMasterKey"
    DATABASE_URI: "ReplaceWithDatabaseURI"
    NODE_ENV: "production"
    SERVER_URL: "http://myappname.elasticbeanstalk.com/parse"
    FILE_KEY: "Parse Filekey"
```

If there a key missing?

Also, is there any special considerations or modifications that are required for FILE_KEY?  Is it just the FILE_KEY from Parse, or does it also need massaging (e.g. an additional prefix)?

Comment: I do not use ParseFile, but it seems need a filesAdapter. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-File-Adapters
And there is a discussion of ParseFile. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/8

Comment: Thanks @ChunTingLin, I am having trouble with a special case -- accessing legacy PFFiles managed by Parse, in which case  do not have to specify a filesAdapter but must provide a fileKey.  Nevertheless, I have explicitly parameterized a filesAdapter (and many other permutations of keys and version numbers) to no avail.  I have worked this problem for a few weeks.  Nothing works.  I believe I must have some sort of corruption in the legacy database.  So, I am giving up and moving forward with the generation of new database.  Just glad that I am only in development.